# How to change the cylinder on this Esety barlock?

Tags: doors, lock

My main door has a vertical reinforcement bar that locks into the ground and above the door. Unfortunately, it does not share the same key as the main door lock on the left.

I would like to replace both cylinders in order to use the same key for both, and ideally use a more secure key mechanism.

How should I proceed to replace the cylinder on the barlock? I do not see any way to open it or remove it. The brand is Esety but it seems it was acquired by Mul-T-Lock in 2007, and their original website does not exist anymore (I could only find [an archive of their old catalogue](https://web.archive.org/web/20041019224524/http://www.esety.com/eng/sbarre.asp), which mentions vertical bars, but I don't find mine). I am located in Belgium, if that matters.

[image: Esety bar]

Close-up of the barlock cylinder, its brand is Iseo:

[image: Barlock cylinder close-up]
[image: Barlock cylinder face-on]
(I damaged the paintig a bit more when trying to remove the cover between the two pictures)

I was able to pry the cover of the bar itself at the top and the bottom of the door, but not at the level of the lock. Instead, it is the lock that is coming out of the door (which actually seems like a flaw since you can push it from the outside!). See these side views of the top and the lock:

[image: Barlock top – pried cover]
[image: Barlock pried lock]
(note that the door is glossy, hence the reflection)

I can remove the cylinder of the door's main lock without problem, it is 6cm long and symmetrical:

[image: Main lock cylinder]

Both keys have the same profile, so I could re-key the main lock, but I would like also to use more secure locks if possible.

Comment: I would think that a locksmith could easily tell you if they can be keyed the same and what would be required.

Comment: I take it both keys are standard pin-tumbler keys (with the jagged edge that interfaces to the pins in the lock) with no funny features on them (such as dimples or such), no? Also, can you post close-ups of both locks?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes, the keys are the old classic ones – I think it's called euro-profile? This is also a reason to change them to something more secure. I added a close-up picture of the barlock's cylinder (Iseo branded), and of the main lock's cylinder, which I can remove without issue.

Comment: If you just want them to be keyed the same, see if the barlock cylinder key will slide into the main keyway. Doesn't have to turn, but if it fits, take the barlock key and the main cylinder to a locksmith, and they can change the pins so you can use the same key on both. Wouldn't be more secure though. To remove the barlock cylinder, have you looked underneath the cover around the lock cylinder? Maybe there's a small set screw, or a small indent where you can pry with a screwdriver. If not, you may need to remove the entire bar lock assembly to access.

Comment: @DidierL can you get us face-on shots of both locks please?

Comment: @PhilippNagel Yes indeed I did not find any way to pry the cover of the lock itself. I was however able to pry the cover of the bar, and the bar itself – I added more details about it.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I added one for the barlock. I don't think it's worth discussing the main lock much since I can get it out without problem. The key has the same profile so I could maybe re-key it, but it would not improve security.

Comment: @DidierL -- my big question is "what attacks are you up against?" Low-skill burglars performing physical attacks such as kicking in doors, snapping cylinders, and drilling cores are a whole different problem to stop than someone who can sit down and take the time to actually pick a reasonably secure pin-tumbler core -- keep in mind that locks are about difficulty and delay.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, indeed I think my first concern should be low-skill attacks, against which I don't think my current locks are protected. This is for an apartment however, so I suppose an attacker could actually get all the time he needs to pick the lock – but I guess this is less likely to happen.

Comment: Actually a good locksmith would likely still be able to increase security by upgrading the pins and springs in the lock cylinder, there are easy options out there.